# Apache Wink get URLPattern programmatically

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, restful-url

I my web.xml I have definition of JAX-RS:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>applicationConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/resources.properties</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

How can I get apis URLPattern programmatically in code?

Comment: The thing is we already defining path in web.xml, but I want to get it in different part of code. Therefore I asked if this is possible. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject the [`ServletContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) into your resource class (or provider) by using the [`@Context`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Context.html) annotation. From there, you can get a [`ServletRegistration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRegistration.html) from the `ServletContext`. The `ServletRegistration` has a [`getMappings`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRegistration.html#getMappings%28%29) method where you can get the `<url-pattern>`

For example

```
@Path("/test")
public class TestResource {

    @Context
    ServletContext context;

    @GET
    public Response getTest() {
        ServletRegistration registration = 
                context.getServletRegistration("JAX-RS Servlet");
                                                // ^^^ Your servlet name
        Collection<String> mappings = registration.getMappings();
        for (String mapping: mappings) {
            System.out.println("Url Pattern: " + mapping);
        } 
        ...
    }
}
```

This should print out the pattern `/api/*`.

---

**Just for completeness:** For those not using web.xml, and using an `Application` subclass, the name of the servlet will be the fully qualified class name of the `Application` subclass

Comment: thanks, this works ! However in JSP i needed to get ServletContext from HttpServletRequest.